# Regular Expression in SQL - Need to extract the last three sections of a multiline string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am having a heck of a time with this one...
I need to create an SQL query which returns a custom field consisting of the last three sections of a multiline string (CLOB field).  The database is Oracle.  I chose to use the REGEXP_SUBSTR function to try and make this work.  Even though this would be easy to parse using C# or Java, I am restricted to SQL, so I cannot use code to do it.

Here is an example of the data in the original field:

```
2000-01-01: Description section containing any valid text characters, including
    other dates(not followed by a colon), and potentially other hyphenated
    characters.  Potentially has multiple newline characters.
-
2001-01-01: 2nd section with different content, but following same parameters
    as first section.
-
2002-01-01: 3rd section with different content, but following same parameters
    as first section.
-
2003-01-01: 4th section with different content, but following same parameters
    as first section.
-
2004-05-05: 5th section with different content, but following same parameters
    as first section.
```

So, based on the above data, I would want to get the last three sections, which would look like this:

```
2002-01-01: 3rd section with different content, but following same parameters
    as first section.
-
2003-01-01: 4th section with different content, but following same parameters
    as first section.
-
2004-05-05: 5th section with different content, but following same parameters
    as first section.
```

I have tried numerous RegEx expressions, and have been able to match the first few sections in the string, but cannot find a way of restricting it to the last three without inadvertently matching the entire string.

Here is my latest attempt:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(CLOB_FIELD_1, '(<date>.*?-\s+){0,2}(<date>.*?$)', 1, 1, 'n')
FROM MY_TABLE
```

For the sake of readability, I replaced the date-matching regex part with `<date>`.
The actual regex would have the following in it, wherever you see `<date>`:

```
(19|2\d)?\d\d([-/.])(0?[1-9]|1[012])\2(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]):
```

Basically, it is a very restrictive way of matching the date patterns `YYYY-MM-DD:` or `YYYY/MM/DD:` or `YYYY.MM.DD:`.

Using this expression returns the entire string, because of the `.*?$` at the end.
I am pretty sure the `?` is unnecessary, but that was my attempt to make it non-greedy.

I've been all over my favorite [RegEx Reference Site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html), but was unable to find anything that worked.  I spent a lot of time looking at lookahead and lookbehind groupings, but couldn't find a way to make it work.

If anyone can think of a way to accomplish this, slick or not, I would be VERY appreciative.  I am imagining that there should be a simpler way to accomplish this, but I just can't see it, yet.  Any thoughts???

Comment: Why don't you just look for the last three `\n-\n` in the text and select text that follows?

Answer (score 0):

Don`t know Oracle, but I think this will work:

1. First, use the `REVERSE` function on your whole string.
2. use the following regex on the reversed string `((\n|.)*?(<reversedDate>)){3}`. Obviously, I am leaving working out the reversed date to you. Alternatively (not sure how this will look like in Oracle), just copy that three times.
3. Use `REVERSE` again.